# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied on RPI3

Tags: php, python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I use in my Raspberry Pi GrovePi and I want turn on LED from my webpage using PHP but it still write error: IOError: [Errno 13] Persmission denied.

Here is part of my PHP code:

```
    if ($_GET["turnon"] == "true") {
      exec("python /home/pi/Desktop/GrovePi/Software/Python/grove_led_blick.py")
    }
```

Can somebody help me or can me write some tip what can I do?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Does your web server have access to a python executable in this manner? It doesn't have a PATH in the same manner you do at the console. Does it have visibility to /home/...? Most web servers have limited access and visibility to anything outside their environment. In short, you have to start further back here by simply proving to yourself you can invoke an executable like "python" and get it to do something simple (like update a text file so you know it ran.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can I find out if my web server has visibility to /home?

Comment: This is out of scope for [so]. Setting up a web server so it can run things like Python is a subject for your own research, as it requires too many specific details and steps for a simple Q&A. I'd start here: "running python from a web server"